# Removing the load of an AC signal to a DC signal

Tags: audio, adc, load, bridge-rectifier

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOJew7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I built this circuit to visualize music with LED's using a full-bridge rectifier I got from a vacuum(meant for 120VAC to 120VDC, with a 270uF 250V capacitor) and the first part of a flash ADC converter. When the reference voltage for the ADC converter comes from the audio amplifier, the audio amplifier heats up from what seems like an overcurrent draw. Is there any type of circuit that removes the load from the audio amplifier and puts it onto a DC load? Are there any obvious ways I could decrease the current load on the audio amplifier?

Answer (score 1):

Is one of the output terminals of the power amplifier grounded internally?  It often will be.

If so, then by connecting one of the outputs of the rectifier to ground, you are effectively shorting out the amplifier for one half of each AC cycle.

Comment: How would I go about fixing this problem?

Comment: @JacobLara Why are you trying to power your 741's from the rectified signal, rather than whatever your power supply is? Eliminate that, and the grounding problem goes away.

Comment: When I decrease the volume of the music the output also decreases so my visualizer will only work at certain volumes. I'd like the reference voltage of the ADC to change with the volume level.

Comment: @JacobLara the way you've drawn your diagram, it's not just the reference signal that comes from the rectifier, but the power to the op amps as well.  If you just want the reference signal, you can disconnect the ground from the rectifier.

Answer (score 0):

I see ten GND symbols on that diagram.  Is that "groundplane" entirely isolated from the amplifier's "groundplane"?  Or was everything just "grounded to each other" as a matter of course?

Try isolating the two.  Then put a voltmeter or scope on the two groundplanes and see if anything interesting is happening.

It's very likely that the amplifier is designed on the presumption that neither speaker wire will be tied to amplifier groundplane.